# Jenkinsfile with Docker PowerShell image is getting hanged

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline, azure-powershell, docker-image

When the Docker powershell gets invoked from a jenkinsfile it keeps executing and the job doesn't gets terminated.

```
pipeline {
            agent {
        
                    docker {            
                                image 'mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell'
                                args "--mount type=bind,src=/opt,dst=/opt -i -t --entrypoint=''"
                            }
                    }

          
    stages {
            stage('PwShell') {
                    steps {
                        powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Write-Output "PowerShell is mighty!"')
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

[jenkin-job-hang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRzx6.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any log details it's tough to pin point the error as why it is stuck. Generally, for Jenkins declarative pipeline like the following -

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image '...abc.com' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the Pipeline executes, Jenkins will automatically start the specified container and execute the defined steps within it:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
[guided-tour] Running shell script
+ node --version
v14.15.0
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
```

And since you are stuck in the PowerShell line in the steps, it means the steps is not correctly set.

If you check this  [Microsoft PowerShell Support for Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/) document then you will find that by default **returnStdout** returns the standard output stream with a default encoding of UTF-8. And **Write-Output** cmdlet returns an output stream.

You should be able to solve your problem by following the changing your PowerShell line as the code snippet shown below.

```
steps {
    def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Write-Output "PowerShell is mighty!"')
    println msg
}
```

Check this [example](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/#examples) section of the same above mentioned document for more detailed operations on the PowerShell steps.
I would also suggest to read this [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#using-docker-with-pipeline) document for more information.